# Is ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT better performing than ROLLBACK TRANSACTION?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have a script that performs a bunch of updates on a moderately large (approximately 6 million rows) table, based on data read from a file.

It currently begins and then commits a transaction for each row it updates and I wanted to improve its performance somehow. I wonder if starting a single transaction at the beginning of the script's run and then rollbacking to individual savepoints in case any validation error occurs would actually result in a performance increase.

I looked online but haven't had much luck finding any documentation or benchmarks.

Comment: What kind of errors are you handling there? Maybe using `insert on conflict` would be a better solution, so that you don't get an error in the first place. But without seeing the code, this is hard to answer.

Comment: Since you commit each row, if your script were to fail halfway through (say, a power outage), how would you figure out where to pick up again?  The answer to that dictates the range of options you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COMMIT` is mostly an I/O problem, because the transaction log (WAL) has to be synchronized to disk.

So using subtransactions (savepoints) will verylikely  boost performance. But beware that using more than 64 subtransactions per transaction will again hurt performance if you have concurrent transactions.

If you can live with losing some committed transactions in the event of a database server crash (which is rare), you could simply set `synchronous_commit` to `off` and stick with many small transactions.

Another, more complicated method is to process the rows in batches without using subtransactions and repeating the whole batch in case of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Having a single transaction with only 1 COMMIT should be faster than having multiple single row update transactions because each COMMIT must synchronize WAL writing to disk. But how really faster it is in a given environment depends a lot of the environment (number of transactions, table structure, index structure, UPDATE statement, PostgreSQL configuration, system configuration etc.): only you can benchmark in your environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Unfortunately, having a single error in the input file rollback the entire transaction is not really feasible in my case. :(